# iOS 7 - TableView not displaying values properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Sorry but I've been stuck in this problem for quite some time and I can't figure out why. I have a ViewController that has 2 TableViews, it took me some time to manage the functions but it's running well now. Initially, I had some static strings as display for the table cells just to check if I can make it run. After managing to do so, I then used my Arrays as sources for the table contents. The first table populates just fine, however, the second one displays blanks.

The cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *priceCell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PriceCellIdentifier];
    UITableViewCell *discountCell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DiscountCellIdentifier];

    if(tableView == self.priceTable){
        [priceCell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithString:[priceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        return priceCell;
    }
    else /*if(tableView == self.discountTable)*/ {
        [discountCell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithString:[discountArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        return discountCell;
    }

}
```

This is rather confusing since I didn't do anything but change where I am getting the value that the table cell would display. I also checked my `discountArray` and it is not empty, I logged out the values from inside this function and I can see the said values.

**EDIT**

Here is my viewDidLoad function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    priceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    discountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"received info %@", [self.selectedItem description]);
    [self executeSQL];

}
```

executeSQL is the function that would initialise the `priceArray` and `discountArray`

```
- (void) executeSQL{
  // Getting the database path.
  NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"itemList.db"];

  FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
  [database open];

  NSMutableString *sqlQuery = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"SELECT ITEMNAME, BRAND, GROUPID, CLASS, UOM, AMT, AMT2, AMT3, DISC, DISC2, DISC3 FROM ItemList WHERE ITEMNAME = '"];

  [sqlQuery appendString:selectedItem];
  [sqlQuery appendString:@"'"];


  // Query result
  FMResultSet *resultsWithNameLocation = [database executeQuery:sqlQuery];

  [priceArray removeAllObjects];
  [discountArray removeAllObjects];

  //we get the results here.
  while([resultsWithNameLocation next]) {

      //for the AMT, AMT2, and AMT3
      if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"AMT"]] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]){
          [priceArray addObject:@""];
      }
      else{
          [priceArray addObject:[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"AMT"]];
      }

      if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"AMT2"]] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]){
          [priceArray addObject:@""];
      }
      else{
          [priceArray addObject:[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"AMT2"]];
      }

      if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"AMT3"]] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]){
          [priceArray addObject:@""];
      }
      else{
          [priceArray addObject:[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"AMT3"]];
      }
      //end of priceArray

      //for DISC, DISC2, and DISC3

      if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"DISC"]] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]){
          [discountArray addObject:@""];
      }
      else{
          [discountArray addObject:[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"DISC"]];
      }

      if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"DISC2"]] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]){
          [discountArray addObject:@""];
      }
      else{
          [discountArray addObject:[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"DISC2"]];
      }

      if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"DISC3"]] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]){
          [discountArray addObject:@""];
      }
      else{
          [discountArray addObject:[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"DISC3"]];
      }

      NSLog(@"DISC = %@", discountArray[0]);
      NSLog(@"DISC2 = %@", discountArray[1]);
      NSLog(@"DISC3 = %@", discountArray[2]);

  }
  [database close];

}
```

The log statements of the `executeSQL` function execute first before the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function which tell me that my arrays have contents. They are not just being displayed properly.

I am confused because if I replace `[discountCell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithString:[discountArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];` with `[discountCell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sample Text"]];` then it works.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: put breakpoint and see whether it goes inside that else part??

Comment: I placed a log line there and yes it goes inside the else part. Also, I know it goes to the else part because when I use a static string, the 2nd table gets populated.

Comment: have you set delegate for both tables

Comment: How do you obtain the data? Is there maybe an async network call to fetch them? Can you post any relevant code?

Comment: I obtain the data via a sql query to the database stored in the application. I shall edit my post.

Comment: Edited with more code.

Comment: You need to reload the tableView in order to ask again your datasource for data. Something like `[self.tableView reloadData]` after you fill your arrays.

Comment: What is this [discountArray addObject:@""]; for? Why do you add empty string to the array? What is the purpose of doing so? I suspect that [discountArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] is an empty string. Can you try to NSLog it out to see if there is any value?

Comment: I didn't want to display (null) so I placed a blank string instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have missed to set the delegate for your second `UITableView`. If you have not done it, set it in `viewDidLoad`.

Double check your storyboard for your tableviews to be Dynamic. Also, are you returning the correct number of rows in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb but is it different as to when I set the delegate at the Storyboard?

Comment: No there's really no difference. And there's no such question as dumb so no worries.

Comment: This is rather confusing, I have reconnected the dataSource and delegate Outlets of the TableView to the View Controller in the Storyboard and it still refuses to work. 

And if I missed out on setting the delegate for the second TableView, I wouldn't be able to display static strings right?

Comment: For that you need to make sure, same view controller class have both tableview objects in storyboard. If you have set the outlets of table view, you can manage it with that too in cellForRowAtIndexpath method.

Comment: Double check your storyboard for your tableviews to be Dynamic. Also, are you returning the correct number of rows in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:?

Comment: I switched out my `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView`. Thank you. I can't believe I wasted 1.5 hours on this silly problem.